# Did any contemporary sources write about Jesus?

Tags: christianity, jesus

Did anyone write about Jesus at the time at which he was alive?

I can't find any sources from the time in which he was alive after a quick preliminary search.

Comment: No. And very long time after his death, no sources except Gospels mention him. The only "independent" ancient author who mentions his story at all is Josephus, but many speculate that this is a later interpolation.

Comment: @Alex Some suspect the passage is in part an interpolation, not the whole thing. Josephus mentions Christians and Jesus.

Comment: Strictly speaking, no one whose writings survived wrote about Jesus.

Comment: Define "contemporary"? Sources while he was still alive? Sources of people who overlapped with him?

Comment: Technically, someone must have written about him while he was alive - but none of these writings survive.

Comment: I copied the title of your question into google; there were several useful answers in the first five results.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

No, nobody did. Despite the fact that literacy was relatively high amongst the Jews at that time. And we have several historians living there or in the area in those days. Jesus was mentioned outside the gospels a few times, but those lines are generally seen as either pious forgeries or out of context.

Josephus mentions Jesus, but it doesn't fit in the text and contradicts Josephus own religious ideas.

Pliny the Younger mentions Christians, as followers of a certain Crestos or Christos. He doesn't go into the existence of Jesus, merely asking the emperor what to do with his followers. Pliny lived a century later, by that time there were Christians. It doesn't prove Jesus lived, it proved Christians existed.

Now, since we're in the realm of religion here, I always wondered why nobody outside the bible mentions that the dead walked the streets of Jerusalem upon the death of Jesus. (Matt 27:50-54) You'd think this was something rather remarkable, worthy enough to write down for posterity or inform friends about. But nobody did. At least the governor should have informed his emperor about this rather unusual event. But even he didn't.

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Josephus_on_Jesus
- http://www.josephus.org/testimonium.htm
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pliny_the_Younger_on_Christians
- https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Matthew+27:50-54
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tacitus_on_Jesus

Comment: Concerning your third paragraph: As far as contemporary accounts are concerned, the eruption of the Vesuvius, to give just a very basic example, is only mentioned in two letters of Pliny, addressed to Tacitus.

Comment: It would be more correct to say that the histories of Josephus contain a passage about Jesus, rather then "Josephus mentions Jesus".

Comment: This would be a good answer, except for the red herring about "the dead walking the streets", which has nothing to do with the question that was asked.

Comment: Given the reality of the time, it's not surprising nobody would write specifically about any particular rogue Jewish prophet or messiah. There were dozens, if not hundreds such wandering the land with little groups of devotees and followers. They were an eyesore on the established priesthood but little could be done about them unless they appeared to become too popular. Where Jesus (if he existed) seems to have been different is that he actively preached against the financial riches the temples harboured while the people at large remained poor. THAT got the priesthood angry enough.

Comment: The short answer, from a Christian perspective, is that the authors of the Gospels were either eyewitnesses or close associates of eyewitnesses. See Christianity SE. They were likely too busy to write & publish reports while following Jesus for three years. The reason why others may not have cared about reports of resurrected saints appearing, is that that appearances might have only occurred to "some" as mere fleeting ghost like apparitions that went thorough walls & locked doors much like Jesus did after his resurrection.  (Matthew 27:50-54)

Comment: @Jess The other answer, from a historic perspective, is that there is no independent proof that *any* kind of miracles *ever* happened, at *any* point of time, for *any* faith. {shrug}

Comment: @DevSolar The need for "independent" proof for the events of the life of Jesus is not necessary for those who prefer to believe in the claims of those who were eyewitnesses & or close associates of the eyewitnesses of Jesus' life. The traditional Christian worldview is that of holding to an open epistemology that does not rule out metaphysical explanations. See https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/92218/what-is-an-overview-of-christian-epistemological-views-on-scientific-skepticism/92222#92222 & https://christianity.stackexchange.com/a/92222/54773

Comment: @Jess Sorry, not interested in what Christians think.

Comment: @jwenting: Indeed.  To Christians, the crucifixion of Jesus was the most important event in history.  But to the Romans, it was just another Friday.

Comment: We don't know that nobody wrote about Jesus in his time. We only know that no writings from that time about Jesus have survived the intervening 2000 years. It's more than possible that somebody wrote a letter about him, or the Jewish rulers recorded events around him, but those records did not survive.

Answer (score 11):

None that we know of. And actually Jesus wasn't unique in that regard. There were a lot of ancient figures who we know existed, but nearly everything we have written about them was from after their deaths (Alexander the Great, for example).

I'm going to guess, though, that what you're really asking is whether or not Jesus existed. The short answer is yes. He did! Very few historians worth their salt would question that, Christian or otherwise. Evidence that someone named Jesus lived during the First Century in Judea, was crucified, and was the central figure of Christianity is so rampant as to be virtually indisputable. This evidence includes the written account of Tacitus, who mentions Jesus and who was so hostile towards Christians that his passage is almost certainly not a Christian alteration of the original text. Furthermore, the existence of Jesus is supported by models such as the Criterion of Multiple Attestation and the Criterion of Embarrassment.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Criterion_of_embarrassment

http://www.npr.org/2012/04/01/149462376/did-jesus-exist-a-historian-makes-his-case

Comment: Good point about just how limited our contemporary information about *anything* in ancient times is and how very, very little has survived.

Answer (score 10):

If the question is did anybody write about Jesus before his crucifixion then the answer is **No**.

If the question is are there Contemporary sources who wrote about Jesus then the answer is **Yes**.

While no sources are known who wrote of Jesus before the crucifixion there are writings by a contemporary of Jesus ([4,6BCE–30CE](https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.ancient.eu/amp/1-12343/)) who talked with and wrote of people who knew Jesus.  Also Josephus is not dismissed by most scholars as an independent verification of Jesus’s life.

Contemporary means living at the same time.  The oldest books of the New Testament  Romans, Corinthians, and Galatians take the form of letters from Saint Paul ([4BCE–62CE](https://www.britannica.com/biography/Saint-Paul-the-Apostle)) to early church leaders ([dated 55, 56, 57 CE](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dating_the_Bible)). And stories about St Paul’s experiences.  St Paul was a contemporary of Jesus being about the same age as Jesus.  Although Paul states he had never met Jesus before the  crucifixion.  He discusses meeting in his letters with St. Peter who was one of the apostles who knew and walked with Jesus.

The earliest letters of St. Paul predate Josephus by about 40 -50 years.  But Josephus also contain two references to Jesus (books 18, 20) only one of which is contested. The contested verse is not thought to be entirely false insertion but to have been modified. The other verse from book 20 is not questioned for its authenticity.

> ## Josephus on Jesus
>
> - **[SOURCE](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Josephus_on_Jesus)**
>   Modern scholarship has largely acknowledged the authenticity of the reference in Book 20, Chapter 9, 1 of the Antiquities to "the brother of Jesus, who was called Christ, whose name was James"[12] and considers it as having the highest level of authenticity among the references of Josephus to Christianity.

---

I also disagree with the above answer that literacy was wide spread in Jesus's time in Judea.  I would also argue that literacy was less relevant than literacy in Greek or Latin which was even less common in the region.  Extremely uncommon among Christians before Paul who is first credited with:

- Spreading Christianity beyond it's Jewish roots outside Judea
- Writing the earliest part of the Christian New Testament in Greek
- Translating the **[Septuagint](https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.ancient.eu/amp/1-12343/)** which we know today.

**Mainly the [Deuterocanonical books of the Old Testament](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deuterocanonical_books):**

- Tobit
- Judith
- Wisdom (also called the Wisdom of Solomon)
- Sirach (also called Ecclesiasticus)
- Baruch, including the Letter of Jeremiah (Additions to Jeremiah in the Septuagint)[1](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Josephus_on_Jesus)
- 1 Maccabees
- 2 Maccabees
- Additions to Esther (Vulgate Esther 10:4 to 16:24)[2](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dating_the_Bible)
- Additions to Daniel:
  Prayer of Azariah and Song of the Three Holy Children (Vulgate Daniel 3:24–90)
- Susanna (Vulgate Daniel 13, Septuagint prologue)
- Bel and the Dragon (Vulgate Daniel 14, Septuagint epilogue)

(Prior to Paul most of the old testament had been translated into Greek (mid-3rd BCE), a language consumable to non Jewish Roman Citizens.).

Comment: Not that St. Paul is his catholic name - for me a protestant he simply "Paul" or "Paul of Thrace".

Comment: @Bregalad - That's not a universal Protestant thing either though. Lutherans, Episcopalians, Presbyterians, and Methodists all have saints. There's a "[St. Paul's Methodist Church](http://stpaulstulsa.com/)" about 8 miles from my house.

Comment: @Bregalad More basic: Paul is his Greek name, Saul his Jewish name, no road accident needed, right to the end.

Comment: @JMS You answer the headline, but the body is different: "write about Jesus *at* the time at which he was alive". Alive=before Easter/Crucifixion. That is *certainly* not Paul! As you acknowledge. Not one person wrote about him, while he was still alive, that we know of. Debate about Historical Jesus aside, exact date aside, dead allegedly around 33 allegedly first surviving text about that mid-40*s the earliest = NO!.

Comment: @LangLangC,  you are correct.   we agree on the facts, we agree on what my answer is saying, we just disagree on what the question is asking.   The title asks for contemporary sources which is Paul.  The second sentence "sources from the time Jesus was alive",  is satisfied by St Peter who Paul converses with and quotes in Galations.   But you are correct.  No writings about Jesus,  while Jesus was alive.

Comment: Yet, unless you make this clear: explicit divide between what you write and the Q asks (it has two angles that are incongruent, arguably), then I think the first word of your answer is misleading. – It's not a bad thing to correct the phrasing or meaning of a Q *explicitly* in an A. You do that partially with "contemporary means" but start the A with "Yes, while no". A bit more spelling out and a bit more streamlined writing is what I tried to convey.

Comment: @LangLangC,  you are right again,  I will work on correcting my answer.  Thank You.

Comment: Nice. But, hm, Paul "translating the Septuagint"? Into what? The [LXX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Septuagint) was already in Greek, 'complete(ly)', and he mostly used it for writing letters/preaching to the [Greeks, Romans, Pagans, Gentiles], thereby enhancing its popularity among pagan Christians, and the world/church, among other effects. The last para needs backup (& I guess there is a mixup of some sort?)

Comment: @LangLangC,  you're kicking my ass tonight!!...   I'll fix it,  I'll fix it.   What I was going for was the the Torah or Pentateuch were translated prior to Paul,  but Paul completed the Septuagint that we know today..  which includes the deuterocanonical books.   And thank you.

Comment: Paul also talks about meeting Jesus's brother James in Jerusalem in Galatians (as well as Peter as you say).  This answer also might be improved by emphasizing that it's the *authentic* letters of Paul (1 Thessalonians, Romans, Galatians, 1&2 Corinthians, Philippians, and perhaps one or two others) that are written by a contemporary.  Most scholars do not think that something like 1 Timothy was written before Josephus.

Comment: The idea that the New Testament was written, so it could match the prophecies of the Old Testament, seems fairly obvious. Citing the OT as evidence for Jesus existence is pretty farfetched.

Comment: We don't know that nobody wrote about Jesus in his time. We only know that no writings from that time about Jesus have survived the intervening 2000 years. It's more than possible that somebody wrote a letter about him, or the Jewish rulers recorded events around him, but those records did not survive.

Answer (score 4):

The first part of Joseph Klausner's [*Jesus of Nazareth: His Life, Times, and Teaching*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0819705659) contains a rather thorough discussion of the existing sources, even though it has to be noted, that the book is several decades old, and some recent archeological findings or research are not reflected there (e.g., it dismisses tegerences to Jesus in Josephus' writings, mentioned in another answer).

More specifically, the first three books of the New Testament are retellings of the same Hebrew or Aramaic source, likely written by a Jesus' contemporary.

Jesus is also mentioned in many contemporary Jewish writings (Talmuds, etc.), although he often appears there under different names, so establishing his identity requires historical research. (And he is obviously not treated as a son of the Almighty, but as a sage/rabbi.)

Klausner's overall conclusion is that we have more evidence of Jesus' existence, than we have about Socrates, even though no one doubts the existence of the latter.

Answer (score 1):

As a lot of people have said, there are many people who were mostly only written about after their death in the ancient world. However, there were people who wrote about Jesus around the time of his existence and his execution that were not Christian like Roman historian & senator Tacitus. One of the passage of his work Annals talks about the execution of Jesus:

> "called Christians by the populace. Christus, from whom the name had its origin, suffered the extreme penalty during the reign of Tiberius at the hands of one of our procurators, Pontius Pilatus."

Scholars generally say that it is authentic since many of the events mentioned in the book also match up with records of other events at the time. Historian [William L. Portier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sources_for_the_historicity_of_Jesus#Key_sources) even stated that there was consistency between the references by Tactitus, Josephus (a Jewish historian who wrote about Jesus), and letter from Pliny the Younger to the Emperor Trajan (where he wrote about "Christus", which makes since many historians like Charles Guignebert don't doubt that Jesus lived in or or near Gallilee in the first century). So historians generally agree with evidence like this that Jesus probably existed and wasn't just a myth: it is just simply a possibly that a popular Jewish teacher who was executed as a heretic was mythologized (which was pretty common in the era and even in times near common day, like how [George](https://www.jstor.org/stable/26854498) [Washington](https://daijingutemple.org/home/about/) has been worshipped as god by Hawaiian Shintoists for years even though most of us see him as just a man & how the [inventor](http://www.esperantic.org/wp-content/uploads/2016/06/LLZ-Bio-En.pdf) of the language Esperanto L. L. Zamenhof was made a spiritual deity in the [Oomoto](http://www.oomoto.or.jp/English/enFaq/indexfaq.html) religion).

Comment: Or Prince Philip, worshipped by people in Vanuatu.

Comment: I rather thought the clumsy inserts in Josephus were not taken seriously by historians.

Answer (score -1):

Heres the josephus passage from an Arabic translation from the 10th century, a lot more neutral. “At this time there was a wise man who was called Jesus. And his conduct was good, and [he] was known to be virtuous. And many people from among the Jews and the other nations became his disciples. Pilate condemned him to be crucified and to die. And those who had become his disciples did not abandon his discipleship. They reported that he had appeared to them three days after his crucifixion and that he was alive. Accordingly, he was perhaps the Messiah concerning whom the prophets have recounted wonders.” (10th Century Arabic Text)

Comment: Please cite your sources, with a link if possible. Are you aware of [Internet Digital Archive](https://archive.org/)?